# How can a SortedList slip its keys?

Tags: c#, sortedlist

I have a SortedList that occasionally re-assigns its keys to different values, and I don't understand how this could happen.

I know that the keys and values are getting out-of-sync because the values are objects that contain a property that is supposed to be equal to the key.

The initialization is like:

```
class MyObject
{
  int IndexProperty { get; set; }

  // ... other properties
}

SortedList<int, SortableObject> mySortedList =
  new SortedList<int, MyObject>(sourceList.ToDictionary(x => x.IndexProperty , x => x)));

// sourceList is a pre-existing List<MyObject>
```

When this is done, mySortedList looks like:

```
{
  2, {IndexProperty = 2}
  7, {IndexProperty = 7}
  22, {IndexProperty = 22}
  45, {IndexProperty = 45}
}
```

The only manipulation of mySortedList that occurs after initialization is that from time to time:

```
AdvanceToNext()
{
  if (mySortedList.Count > 0)
  {
    mySortedList.RemoveAt(0);
  }
}
```

Usually, there's no problem, but every once in a while, this check trips:

```
if (mySortedList.Any(pair => pair.Key != pair.Value.IndexProperty))
  ; // Should never get here.
```

and inspection of the contents of mySortedList indicates that all of the values have shifted with respect to the keys:

```
{
  7, {IndexProperty = 2}
  22, {IndexProperty = 7}
  45, {IndexProperty = 22}
}
```

What could cause this to happen?

Comment: Are you using threads, i.e. one thread writes to the list, other thread(s) remove from that list?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl No threads. The only writing into the list comes during initialization.

Comment: Another guess - I just noticed that IndexProperty is public-set (or rather, not specified i nthe piece you provided) -- could you check references and see where it is **set**? Are there any chances that some rogue old piece of code sets a new value after an item has been added to the list?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the only time SortableObject.IndexProperty is getting set is in SortableObject's constructor.

Comment: @IsaacMoses In that case you can make it readonly by removing the `set`.

Comment: There is something certainly missing here. Try to remove `set` as suggested to verify that there are no other places where `IndexProperty` is modified